# Batch file to start all programmes in the start folder of XP

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-xp, startup

I need start all folders in a the Windows "Start/Programs/Startup folder" of an XP machine, explorer is disabled to stop top people playing and remove the Start and Task-bar.

I can run a batch file at start-up but how do I write the batch to run ALL programs in the "Start/Programs/Startup folder" the programs in the folder may change but the batch needs to remain the same

I am able to open each file individually using the below code but I really need to be able to open everything in the folder to avoid problems in the future

```
start "" /b "C:\Documents and Settings\User\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\PROG.appref-ms"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the code below, that batch starts but nothing starts

```
%DIR%=C:\Documents and Settings\Pete\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
for %%a in (%DIR%\*) do "%%a"
```

Running the batch from the desktop also doesn't run the programs in the start folder, the DIR address is taken from windows explorer when I navigated to the folder with the short cuts in

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in my answer. I have corrected it so give it a try now.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work a treat, I have used the below code to test the system, which worked quite well although only opened the files by name, but it did prove the theory.
start "" /b "C:\Documents and Settings\User\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\PROG.appref-ms"

Comment: The CMD window remained open at the end of the process using your method which it didn't before, so I have added "exit 0" at the end to close it

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting request--one that I would question the motive behind, but since you asked, here's a way you could accomplish it:

```
@echo off    
set DIR=C:\Your\Directory
for %%a in ("%DIR%\*") do "%%a"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll try it tomorrow, The motive behind it is very simple, it is an industrial PC that is used in a factory to display a screen, but the operators have a habit of messing about and they have changed IP addresses before, which stops the application communicating, so it is a simple way to lock them out by changing the "Shell" from explorer to run a simple batch, which removes the Start menu and teaskbar, without explorer running the programs in Startup won't start, which is why I need the batch file